# "Could not resolve "vscode"" error after project structure refactoring

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, esbuild

I'm developing a vscode extension and up to now everything works fine.
Yesterday I had to refactor my project structure and inserted the path aliases feature in order to get rid of relative paths during imports. Now the problem is that, at compile time, it doesn't work anymore: indeed, the compiler says `Could not resolve "vscode"` and I really don't know why.

I tried with deleting **node_modules** and **package-lock.json** in order to get rid of some sort of cache, but no further improvements from this move.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: can you compile the examples